# Optimization through code for gcc?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, gcc

Is there any way to tell GCC through code that I want it to optimize my code?
or can it be done only by command line settings (e.g. "`gcc source.c -O2 -o out`")?

Comment: Of course you can further optimize your code by straightening to some specific C++ programming paradigms as well!